My laptop (a Dell Inspiron) has started boot looping after I Connected a 12v power source to my Arduino that was connected to my laptop
My Dell Inspiron has started boot looping after I connected a 12v power source to my Arduino that was connected to my laptop.
I was trying to run a DC motor using the L293D motor controller, and I was feeding it 12v from a power supply, when I moved one of the cables the Arduino lights suddenly got very bright and my laptop screen went dark.
Now it won't get past loading screen.
Does anyone know how I could fix this?

yes, the Dell service department knows how to fix it

where did you connect the 12 V power supply to the arduino?

It seems that the 12v went through the 5v and ground pins on the arduino.

what do you mean by it seems? ... do you not know how the 12 V power supply was connected?

There is not enough info to answer definitively, but it seems you might have damaged hardware.

Try booting from USB (e.g. WinPE or WinRE, or Linux, such as Live Ubuntu. If that works, there is no major issue with the PC -- you might need to reinstall OS, or replace the drive, but those are easily done.
If the PC fails to boot from external media, likely hardware was fried and needs professional repair.

